# Why am I getting a different result using command in function vs command line?

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a simple function in bash to search the first line of a CSV file and return the column number of a matching header value:

```
findcolnum()
{
    colnum=`head -1 $1 | awk -F"," '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if($i==$2) {print i}}'`
    echo $colnum
}
```

When I make the call to the function:

```
analogcol=`findcolnum "$DIR/PCICCP_AnalogPoint_DMS.csv" "AnalogPointRef"`
```

The result is always "2" no matter whether the column exists or not.

While on command line, where I tested the command before putting it into a script, it is returning the correct value:

```
head -1 Outbox/ICCP/PCICCP_AnalogPoint_DMS.csv | awk -F"," '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if($i=="AnalogPointRef") {print i}}'
9
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: `$2` inside `awk` doesn't refer to your external variable, but to a temporary variable inside `awk`

Comment: Untested, but try `colnum=\`head -1 $1 | awk -F"," '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if($i=='$2') {print i}}'\``. That is, take the `$2` variable outside the `awk` context (by stopping and starting the single-quoted string).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I will play around with it to figure it out. Also, off-topic but, my name is Benjamin W as well haha...

Comment: @bw Ha! There are apparently more than 100 of us on Stack Overflow ;) https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=week&search=benjamin+w

Comment: Rather than going to the trouble of doing `colnum=`head -1 $1 | awk -F"," '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if($i==$2) {print i}}'`; echo $colnum`, you could save yourself (and the  shell) some trouble by just using `head -1 $1 | awk -F"," '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if($i==$2) {print i}}'

Comment: Also in addition to the [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) you could avoid the separate `head` with `awk -F , 'NR==1{ for(i...`